# RxJava operator Debounce is not working

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2, debouncing

I want to implement place autocomplete in Android application, and for this I'm using Retrofit and RxJava. I want to make response every 2 seconds after user type something. I'm trying to use debounce operator for this, but it's not working. It's giving me the result immediately without any pause.

```
 mAutocompleteSearchApi.get(input, "(cities)", API_KEY)
            .debounce(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(prediction -> Observable.fromIterable(prediction.getPredictions()))
            .subscribe(prediction -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "rxAutocomplete : " + prediction.getStructuredFormatting().getMainText());
            });
```

Comment: It looks like you're debouncing the network call. Probably you should be debouncing the user input events instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @BenP says in the comment, you appear to be applying `debounce` to the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) service. This call will return an Observable that emits a single result (or error) before completing, at which point the `debounce` operator will emit that one and only item.

What you probably want to be doing is debouncing the user input with something like:

```java
// Subject holding the most recent user input
BehaviorSubject<String> userInputSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();

// Handler that is notified when the user changes input
public void onTextChanged(String text) {
    userInputSubject.onNext(text);
}

// Subscription to monitor changes to user input, calling API at most every
// two seconds. (Remember to unsubscribe this subscription!)
userInputSubject
    .debounce(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap(input -> mAutocompleteSearchApi.get(input, "(cities)", API_KEY))
    .flatMap(prediction -> Observable.fromIterable(prediction.getPredictions()))
    .subscribe(prediction -> {
        Log.e(TAG, "rxAutocomplete : " + prediction.getStructuredFormatting().getMainText());
    });
```

Comment: @ViktorYakunin The intent here is to prevent making the autocomplete network call every single time the user input changes. Debounce allows us to reliably process new user input, but limits it to at most one call every two seconds (even if the input is changing more rapidly than that). http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html

Comment: Any reason why it is flatMap instead of switchMap?