# Retrofit + Debouce on EditText is causing an InterruptedIOException

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

I currently have an `EditText` for the user to enter a search. I'm trying to use RxJava with `debounce` to only search every so often, instead of each character. However, I'm getting an `InterruptedIOException` while I'm testing, which kills the stream.

```
private val subject = BehaviorSubject.create<String>()

init {
    configureAutoComplete()
}

private fun configureAutoComplete() {
    subject.debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .flatMap {
            getSearchResults(query = it)
        }
        .subscribe({ result ->
            handleResult(result)
        }, { t: Throwable? ->
            Logger.e(t, "Failed to search")
        })
}

fun getSearchResults(query: String): Observable<List<MyObject>> {
    val service = NetworkService.create() // get retrofit service
    return service.search(query)
}


fun search(text: String) {
    subject.onNext(text)
}
```

As you can see, I'm creating a `BehaviorSubject`, and within `init` I'm setting it up with `debounce`.

`getSearchResult` returns an `Observable` and does my network request.

But as I'm testing, if I type at a specific rate ( usually quick-ish, like typing another character while the request is ongoing ) it'll throw an `Exception`.

```
 Failed to search : java.io.InterruptedIOException
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo(Http2Stream.java:579)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeResponseHeaders(Http2Stream.java:143)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:125)
```

I was looking at this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276430/3106174, and it seems like I'm doing everything correctly.

Comment: Can you add the source code for `getSearchResult()`?

Comment: @DanailAlexiev I've added some details for `getSearchResult`, it's just making a network call via Retrofit, returning an `Observerable` that contains a `List`.

Comment: I would start by increasing the debounce interval and add `distinctUntilChanged()` and `filter()` to remove any empty input. I think your problem may be related to unsubscribing before the HTTP request completes, causing an interruption.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev I tried the 3 suggestions, increasing the debounce interval did make it harder to reproduce, but it still happens if I time it right. It does seem to be related to the HTTP request. Should I be cancelling the in-flight HTTP request if the user types again?

Comment: Also, I realized that if I remove the `debounce`, I'll get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. That doesn't seem right. I feel like I have something wrong with my setup. This is in a `ViewModel`, btw.

Comment: You can try using `service.search(query).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io).observeOn(AndroidShedulers.mainThread()`. This will execute the network call on the main thread and deliver it's result on the main thread.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev I actually managed to figure it out by forcing the subject onto `Scheduler.io`. I've thrown down my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more testing, I realized that the network request was on the main thread.

You can test this by replacing your network call with `Observerable.create{ ... }` and throwing a `Thread.sleep(1000)` inside.

I was following this tutorial, https://proandroiddev.com/building-an-autocompleting-edittext-using-rxjava-f69c5c3f5a40, and one of the comments mention this issue.

> "But I think one thing is misleading in your code snippet, and it’s
>   that subjects aren’t thread safe. And the thread that your code will
>   run on will be the thread that you emitting on (in this case the main
>   thread). "

To solve this issue, you need to force it to run on `Schedulers.io()`. Make sure it's after the `debounce` or it won't work.

```
private fun configureAutoComplete() {
    subject.debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // add this here
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap {
            getSearchResults(query = it)
        }
        .subscribe({ result ->
            handleResult(result)
        }, { t: Throwable? ->
            Logger.e(t, "Failed to search")
        })
}
```